# Fixed width viewport on device larger than said width

Tags: html, mobile, viewport

I have a website optimized for mobile, large fonts, big images, etc. Currently, I have the following viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">
```

Which works just great on all devices I've tested with so far. However, on the iPad (the first one), which has a resolution bigger than 640, I got some white space on the right.

I'd like it so that it just zooms in or out depending on the device, is this something that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `maximum-scale=1` property. Your viewport size (640px) is smaller than the width of the iPad's display, but Safari won't zoom in to get rid of this whitespace because the scale is fixed to 100%. Remove the `maximum-scale=1` property and the whitespace should disappear.

Comment: Doesn't quite work, still have some white space as it's still under 640px, I'd have to use initial-scale=1.2 for the iPad to make it fit.

Comment: My bad. According to the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html), setting the viewport scale to 1.0 will leave whitespace if the viewport is smaller than the device width. You will need to remove the scale settings to get rid of this whitespace. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome! Seemed to have fixed my problem, let me do some testing and I'll accept your answer if everything goes well :)